# Using methods like static methods on classes in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a validation class and I want to use the methods like this:

```
amount: [0, DataInputValidators.validateRange(1,2)],
```

This isn't working it has error:

```
Property 'validateRange' does not exist on type 'typeof DataInputValidators'.
```

**Validation class:**

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

export class DataInputValidators {

  validateRange(min, max) {
    return function (control: AbstractControl) {
      if (control.value < min || control.value > max) {
        return { outOfRange: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: You invoke `validateRange()` as a static method (using the class name, not an instance) but you didn't declare the method as `static` and this is why it doesn't work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a static function, declare the function as static :-)

```
export class DataInputValidators {
  static validateRange(min, max) {
    return function (control: AbstractControl) {
      if (control.value < min || control.value > max) {
        return { outOfRange: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the function keyword after the return statement and keep it outside. It should look like this:

```
function validateRange(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
        if (control.value < min || control.value > max) {
            return { 'outOfRange': true };
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Comment: The function is supposed to return a validator, which is a function. This isn't the issue here.